# Links do cakephp 3.3 estão recebendo a url "var/www/html"

Tags: url, link, cakephp-3

Estou com o seguinte problema, na implementação do site todas os links que foram gerados pelas funções do cakephp como por exemplo:

```
<?= $this->Html->image('logo.png', ['url'=>'/', 'id'=>'logo']) ?>
```

Estão recebendo `var/www/html`, além de repetir o endereço no final ficando dessa maneira: "http://meusite.com.br/var/www/html/meusite.com.br/web/"
alguém ja teve algum problema parecido?

Cheguei a encontrar algo na internet mas a pessoa em questão reinstalou tudo.

Comment: Vê se isso aqui ajuda: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9486191/6101515

Comment: não chegou a resolver o problema, mas deu uma luz, as minhas constantes ROOT, e CORE_PATH, estão retornando /var/www/html/meusite.com.br/web  e acrescentando esse trecho depois do domínio e antes do link que eu adicionei ficando http://meusitecom.br/var/www/html/graficanobairro.com.br/web/pasta/meuarquivo`, o cakephp deve utilizar um desses direta ou indiretamente na função <?= $this->Html->link("nome", "pasta/minhapagina") na hora de montar os links